# Repetition Code - Hamming Bound

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

I want to find the set of integers $n$ for which the repition code of length $n$ is perfect for the alphabet $\{0,1\}$.

The repition code is the code where each letter is repeated $m$-times, the minimum distance is $m$, it is $m-1$ error detecting and $\lfloor 1/2(m-1)\rfloor$-error correcting.

A code is perfect when there is equality in the the Hamming's bound $K\le \frac{2^N}{V(N,e+1)}$ where $c:A\rightarrow\{0,1\}^N$ is an $e$-error correcting code and $K=|A|$ is the number of cde words and $V(N,e+1)=\binom N 0+...+\binom N {e}$.

How can I find the set of integers where the repition code is perfect? Is $N=n$ in our case?

Comment: Hint: Try with $m=N$ being an odd number. Repeat for also $m=N$ being an even number.

Comment: If $m=N$ is odd, then I want to solve $K=\frac{2^m}{V(m,\frac{m+1}{2})}$ to $K$, but how can this term be simplified?

Comment: Further hint: Since $\binom{n}{i} = \binom{n}{n-i}$, $$\binom{2k+1}{0}+\binom{2k+1}{1} + \cdots + \binom{2k+1}{k} = \binom{2k+1}{k+1} + \cdots + \binom{2k+1}{2k} + \binom{2k+1}{2k+1}$$

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see how can simplify everything.
$\binom {2k+1} {2k+1}=1, \binom {2k+1} {2k}=2k+1, \binom {2k+1} {2k-1}=k(2k+1)$, but what about the $i$-th term?

Comment: Last hint: after this you are on your own.  $$\sum_{i=0}^{2k+1} \binom{2k+1}{i} = 2^{2k+1}.$$ What does _that_ tell you about the _numerical value_ of the two sums which my previous hint said were equal? How does this value compare to $2^{2k+1}$?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint #1: A $t$-error correcting code $C$ is perfect, if and only if to **each** received vector $\mathbf{y}$ there is a unique codeword $\mathbf{x}\in C$ such that $d_H(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})\le t.$ This is because the existence of such an $\mathbf{x}$ to all $\mathbf{y}$ means that balls of radii $t$ centered at the codewords cover the entire Hamming space. Uniqueness of $\mathbf{x}$ means that those balls cover the Hamming space without overlap, i.e. the code is perfect.

**Note:** Uniqueness actually follows from the assumption that the code is $t$-error correcting. The covering part is non-trivial.

Hint #2: For which values of $n$ does majority voting among individual bits guarantee the existence of the required word $\mathbf{x}$ of the repetition code, no matter what the received vector $\mathbf{y}$ is?

Moral: Sometimes there are alternatives to counting.